# Android location incorrect

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, android-wifi

This is my case. when the mobile signal is too weak one or two bars. The phone will connect to wifi automatically. After that, when the app try to acquire location. The location is always incorrect. is that gps signal issue?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to use your GPS chip to find your device, Google’s servers “remember” the GPS locations of devices connecting through your router (presumably by associating your location to the router’s MAC address), and “assumes” that all devices connecting through that router are at the location which it remembered. The complete details can be found via below link..  **http://redoubtsolutions.com/android-reports-wrong-location-when-connected-to-wifi/**